# iframe in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

If I put a big iframe on the same page with all the content in the big iframe then can I put the search result onto the big iframe?

any code for it?

Comment: Could you provide more explanation about your use scenario?  You refer to a "big iframe"; is there also a little iframe?  Where is it?  Where are the search results coming from?

Comment: An iframe inside another iframe honestly sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: @MitchDempsey No no no, the idea will never stick. We must go deeper!

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you right you want a iframe with the search results from an other page

```
<form target='theFrame' method='GET' action='http://www.google.nl/search'>

<input type='text' name='q'/>
<input type='submit' value='Google it'/>
</form>
<iframe name='theFrame'></iframe>
```

this example is done with google search.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to put an iframe inside an iframe, but the styling's for the second iframe must be on the page that the first iframe linked to, as the second iframe would be on a different page to the first. (If I understand your question)  hope this helps :)